Am I interpreting R602.7(1) Headers correctly?
Wall Construction R602.7(1)
House details:
House is 1980 single story, slab on grade, 28 feet wide from wall corner to wall corner with 32 foot trusses, 24 OC. Based on a map I determined I'm in the 50psf snow load range. Walls are 2 x 6, 16 OC.
Goal:
Replace a 10 foot bay window and header with two smaller windows and headers, each with a 46 inch rough opening. One header would have a single truss and the other would be supporting two with both being close to what would be the new king studs. Current header would have to be three 2x10.5, so essentially uninsulated. All exterior headers are full height and ripped down to ~10.5.
Aside from it being uninsulated, the inside member is split down the middle horizontally and bowed out slightly, and the center of the top plate is bowed down and has those two or three trusses pinched and under pressure at the next interior mending plate, so I want to lift that center maybe 3/16" to take some pressure off.
Question:
Am I reading correctly that I could get by with a single member 2x12?

What does "current header would have to be" mean? The phrase is self-contradictory. Is that what's there now? Why can't it stay in place?

@isherwood I figured based on the current span that it is more like self-evident, but that is what it is. I cut out some foam from under it and that is what I felt with a screw driver. It could stay in place. Aside from what was already mentioned, If I could go to a single 2x12 with the same amount of studs, given the size of the room that is some good r value to think about. Then there is the placement of the windows without wanting to add on the the existing stud packs, taking away more r value.

From a non engineer and a person not worried about your roof falling on my head, I would look into removing one of your 2x10.5 pieces from the header and adding an 1.5 inch thick piece of foam. With two smaller windows, you will need to add two support studs to hold up the header and frame the windows, anyway. Two 2x10.5s should be plenty for a four foot span max. You do want an expert to check this thinking.

@crip659 This was not a 'what should I do question' it is literally 'Am I reading the table correctly' for which I and still uncertain. This is a very interesting and creative solution. Even with the one cracked almost full length, this thing is a beast. Almost sounds like that would be more work than replacing it, but a outside the box idea that could be a scenario for someone totally unwilling to remove it. Picked up a couple 2x12's for the new window pair to rip down to window height and do two member headers, still get some r-value for the top plate to rough opening.
